# How to read Json file and to make it data frame in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, explode, json-normalize

I want to read json file into pandas and make a data frame for further analysis like reject inferencing.

```
{
  "loans": [
    {
      "loanId": "11111111111111111",
      "TransactionStatus": {
        "ResponseCode": "0",
        "ResponseMessage": "Success",
        "ExtendedErrorDetails": {
          "messages": {
            "code": "0",
            "message": "Success"
          }
        }
      },
      "DCResponse": {
        "Status": "Success",
        "Authentication": {
          "Status": "Success",
          "Token": "222222222222222222222222222222222"
        },
        "ResponseInfo": {
          "ApplicationId": "123456789",
          "SolutionSetInstanceId": "3333333333333333333333333333338"
        },
        "ContextData": {
          "Applicants": {
            "Applicant": {
              "Accounts": {
                "Account": null
              },
              "Addresses": {
                "Address": [
                  {
                    "StateCode": "23",
                    "PinCode": "xxxxxxxxx",
                    "City": "xxxx",
                    "AddressType": "02",
                    "AddressLine3": "xx",
                    "AddressLine2": "xxx",
                    "AddressLine1": "xxxx"
                  },
                  null
                ]
              },
              "Telephones": {
                "Telephone": [
                  {
                    "TelephoneType": "01",
                    "TelephoneNumber": "xxxxxxxxxx"
                  },
                  {
                    "TelephoneType": "02"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "Identifiers": {
                "Identifier": [
                  {
                    "IdType": "01",
                    "IdNumber": "xxxxxxxx"
                  },
                  {
                    "IdType": "02"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "EmailAddress": "xxxxxxxxx",
              "Gender": "Male",
              "DateOfBirth": "000000000",
              "ApplicantLastName": "xxxxx",
              "ApplicantFirstName": "xxxxxx",
              "ApplicantType": "xxxxxxxx",
              "NodeIdentifier": "0",
              "DsCibilBureau": {
                "DsCibilBureauData": {
                  "Request": {
                    "Request": {
                      "ConsumerDetails": {
                        "CreditReportInquiry": {
                          "Header": {
                            "SegmentTag": " TUEF ",
                            "Version": " 12 ",
                            "ReferenceNumber": "234444444444",
                            "MemberCode": "333333333333333333",
                            "Password": null,
                            "Purpose": "05",
                            "Amount": "100",
                            "ScoreType": "08",
                            "OutputFormat": "01",
                            "ResponseSize": "1",
                            "MediaType": "CC",
                            "AuthenticationMethod": "L"
                          },
                          "Names": {
                            "Name": {
                              "ConsumerName1": "xxxxx",
                              "ConsumerName3": "xxxxxx",
                              "DateOfBirth": "000000000",
                              "Gender": "xxxxxx"
                            }
                          },
                          "Identifications": {
                            "Identification": {
                              "PanNo": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                              "PassportNumber": null,
                              "DLNo": null,
                              "VoterId": null,
                              "UId": null,
                              "RationCardNo": null,
                              "AdditionalID1": null,
                              "AdditionalID2": null
                            }
                          },
                          "Telephones": {
                            "Telephone": {
                              "TelephoneNumber": "xxxxxxxxxx",
                              "TelephoneExtension": null,
                              "TelephoneType": "01"
                            }
                          },
                          "Addresses": {
                            "Address": {
                              "AddressLine1": "xxxxxxxx",
                              "AddressLine2": "d,,xxxxx",
                              "AddressLine3": "Default",
                              "AddressLine4": null,
                              "AddressLine5": "xxxxxx",
                              "StateCode": "23",
                              "PinCode": "1111111",
                              "AddressCategory": "02",
                              "ResidenceCode": null
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                "DsCibilBureauStatus": null,
                "Response": {
                  "CibilBureauResponse": {
                    "BureauResponseRaw": "xxxxxxxxxx**",
                    "BureauResponseXml": {
                      "FailureResponse": null,
                      "SucessResponse": {
                        "Header": [
                          {
                            "SegmentTag": "TUEF",
                            "Version": "12",
                            "ReferenceNumber": "353867102",
                            "MemberCode": "333333333333333333",
                            "SubjectReturnCode": "1",
                            "EnquiryControlNumber": "dddddddddddd",
                            "DateProcessed": "01032023",
                            "TimeProcessed": "022959"
                          }
                        ],
                        "NameSegment": [
                          {
                            "SegmentTag": "N01",
                            "Length": "03",
                            "ConsumerName1FieldLength": "05",
                            "ConsumerName1": "xxxx",
                            "ConsumerName2FieldLength": "06",
                            "ConsumerName2": "xxxxx",
                            "DateOfBirthFieldLength": "08",
                            "DateOfBirth": "00000000",
                            "GenderFieldLength": "01",
                            "Gender": "2"
                          }
                        ],
                        "IDSegment": [
                          {
                            "SegmentTag": "I01",
                            "Length": "03",
                            "IDType": "01",
                            "IDNumberFieldLength": "10",
                            "IDNumber": "xxxxxxx"
                          }
                        ],
                        "TelephoneSegment": [
                          {
                            "SegmentTag": "T01",
                            "Length": "03",
                            "TelephoneNumberFieldLength": "10",
                            "TelephoneNumber": "000000000000",
                            "TelephoneType": "01"
                          },
                          {
                            "SegmentTag": "T02",
                            "Length": "03",
                            "TelephoneNumberFieldLength": "10",
                            "TelephoneNumber": "0000000000",
                            "TelephoneType": "01"
                          }
                        ],
                        "ScoreSegment": [
                          {
                            "Length": "10",
                            "ScoreName": "CIBILTUSC3",
                            "ScoreCardName": "08",
                            "ScoreCardVersion": "10",
                            "ScoreDate": "01032023",
                            "Score": "00719",
                            "ReasonCode1FieldLength": "02",
                            "ReasonCode1": "27",
                            "ReasonCode2FieldLength": "02",
                            "ReasonCode2": "25",
                            "ReasonCode3FieldLength": "02",
                            "ReasonCode3": "28",
                            "ReasonCode4FieldLength": "02",
                            "ReasonCode4": "15",
                            "ReasonCode5FieldLength": null,
                            "ReasonCode5": null
                          }
                        ],
                        "Address": [
                          {
                            "AddressSegmentTag": "PA",
                            "Length": "03",
                            "AddressLine1FieldLength": "18",
                            "AddressLine1": "xxxxx",
                            "AddressLine2FieldLength": "18",
                            "AddressLine2": "xxxxxxxxR",
                            "StateCode": "23",
                            "PinCodeFieldLength": "06",
                            "PinCode": "452001",
                            "AddressCategory": "02",
                            "DateReported": "31052022"
                          },
                          {
                            "AddressSegmentTag": "PA",
                            "Length": "03",
                            "AddressLine1FieldLength": "40",
                            "AddressLine1": "xxxxxxx",
                            "AddressLine2FieldLength": "23",
                            "AddressLine2": "xxxxxxxE",
                            "StateCode": "23",
                            "PinCodeFieldLength": "06",
                            "PinCode": "452009",
                            "AddressCategory": "02",
                            "DateReported": "19042019"
                          }
                        ],
                        "Account": [
                          {
                            "Length": "04",
                            "SegmentTag": "T001",
                            "Account_Summary_Segment_Fields": [
                              {
                                "ReportingMemberShortNameFieldLength": "13"
                              }
                            ],
                            "Account_NonSummary_Segment_Fields": [
                              {
                                "ReportingMemberShortNameFieldLength": "13",
                                "ReportingMemberShortName": "NOT DISCLOSED",
                                "AccountType": "02",
                                "OwenershipIndicator": "4",
                                "DateOpenedOrDisbursed": "30012023",
                                "DateReportedAndCertified": "31012023",
                                "HighCreditOrSanctionedAmountFieldLength": "07",
                                "HighCreditOrSanctionedAmount": "1500000",
                                "CurrentBalanceFieldLength": "07",
                                "CurrentBalance": "1200565",
                                "PaymentHistory1FieldLength": "03",
                                "PaymentHistory1": "STD",
                                "PaymentHistoryStartDate": "01012023",
                                "PaymentHistoryEndDate": "01012023",
                                "ValueOfCollateralFieldLength": "07",
                                "ValueOfCollateral": "3850000",
                                "TypeOfCollateralFieldLength": "02",
                                "TypeOfCollateral": "01",
                                "RateOfInterestFieldLength": "04",
                                "RateOfInterest": "9.00",
                                "RepaymentTenureFieldLength": "03",
                                "RepaymentTenure": "106",
                                "EmiAmountFieldLength": "05",
                                "EmiAmount": "16199",
                                "PaymentFrequency": "03"
                              }
                            ]
                          },
                          {
                            "Length": "04",
                            "SegmentTag": "T002",
                            "Account_Summary_Segment_Fields": [
                              {
                                "ReportingMemberShortNameFieldLength": "13"
                              }
                            ],
                            "Account_NonSummary_Segment_Fields": [
                              {
                                "ReportingMemberShortNameFieldLength": "13",
                                "ReportingMemberShortName": "NOT DISCLOSED",
                                "AccountType": "00",
                                "OwenershipIndicator": "4",
                                "DateOpenedOrDisbursed": "30012023",
                                "DateReportedAndCertified": "30012023",
                                "HighCreditOrSanctionedAmountFieldLength": "07",
                                "HighCreditOrSanctionedAmount": "1500000",
                                "CurrentBalanceFieldLength": "07",
                                "CurrentBalance": "1200000",
                                "PaymentHistory1FieldLength": "03",
                                "PaymentHistory1": "STD",
                                "PaymentHistoryStartDate": "01012023",
                                "PaymentHistoryEndDate": "01012023",
                                "ValueOfCollateralFieldLength": "07",
                                "ValueOfCollateral": "3850000",
                                "TypeOfCollateralFieldLength": "02",
                                "TypeOfCollateral": "01",
                                "RateOfInterestFieldLength": "04",
                                "RateOfInterest": "9.00",
                                "RepaymentTenureFieldLength": "03",
                                "RepaymentTenure": "106",
                                "EmiAmountFieldLength": "05",
                                "EmiAmount": "20249",
                                "PaymentFrequency": "03"
                              }
                            ]
                          },
                          {
                            "Length": "04",
                            "SegmentTag": "T003",
                            "Account_Summary_Segment_Fields": [
                              {
                                "ReportingMemberShortNameFieldLength": "13"
                              }
                            ],
                            "Account_NonSummary_Segment_Fields": [
                              {
                                "ReportingMemberShortNameFieldLength": "13",
                                "ReportingMemberShortName": "NOT DISCLOSED",
                                "AccountType": "12",
                                "OwenershipIndicator": "1",
                                "DateOpenedOrDisbursed": "30052022",
                                "DateOfLastPayment": "30052022",
                                "DateReportedAndCertified": "30062022",
                                "CurrentBalanceFieldLength": "01",
                                "CurrentBalance": "0",
                                "PaymentHistory1FieldLength": "06",
                                "PaymentHistory1": "000000",
                                "PaymentHistoryStartDate": "01062022",
                                "PaymentHistoryEndDate": "01052022"
                              }
                            ]
                          },
                          {
                            "Length": "04",
                            "SegmentTag": "T004",
                            "Account_Summary_Segment_Fields": [
                              {
                                "ReportingMemberShortNameFieldLength": "13"
                              }
                            ],
                            "Account_NonSummary_Segment_Fields": [
                              {
                                "ReportingMemberShortNameFieldLength": "13",
                                "ReportingMemberShortName": "NOT DISCLOSED",
                                "AccountType": "00",
                                "OwenershipIndicator": "1",
                                "DateOpenedOrDisbursed": "27042022",
                                "DateOfLastPayment": "02012023",
                                "DateReportedAndCertified": "31012023",
                                "HighCreditOrSanctionedAmountFieldLength": "04",
                                "HighCreditOrSanctionedAmount": "4000",
                                "CurrentBalanceFieldLength": "01",
                                "CurrentBalance": "0",
                                "PaymentHistory1FieldLength": "30",
                                "PaymentHistory1": "000000000000000000000000000000",
                                "PaymentHistoryStartDate": "01012023",
                                "PaymentHistoryEndDate": "01042022"
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        ],
                        "Enquiry": [
                          {
                            "Length": "04",
                            "SegmentTag": "I001",
                            "DateOfEnquiryFields": "21012023",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortNameFieldLength": "13",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortName": "NOT DISCLOSED",
                            "EnquiryPurpose": "02",
                            "EnquiryAmountFieldLength": "07",
                            "EnquiryAmount": "1500000"
                          },
                          {
                            "Length": "04",
                            "SegmentTag": "I002",
                            "DateOfEnquiryFields": "14122022",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortNameFieldLength": "06",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortName": "AU SFB",
                            "EnquiryPurpose": "10",
                            "EnquiryAmountFieldLength": "03",
                            "EnquiryAmount": "100"
                          },
                          {
                            "Length": "04",
                            "SegmentTag": "I003",
                            "DateOfEnquiryFields": "03122022",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortNameFieldLength": "13",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortName": "NOT DISCLOSED",
                            "EnquiryPurpose": "02",
                            "EnquiryAmountFieldLength": "01",
                            "EnquiryAmount": "1"
                          },
                          {
                            "Length": "04",
                            "SegmentTag": "I004",
                            "DateOfEnquiryFields": "16112022",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortNameFieldLength": "13",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortName": "NOT DISCLOSED",
                            "EnquiryPurpose": "02",
                            "EnquiryAmountFieldLength": "06",
                            "EnquiryAmount": "500000"
                          },
                          {
                            "Length": "04",
                            "SegmentTag": "I005",
                            "DateOfEnquiryFields": "16112022",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortNameFieldLength": "13",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortName": "NOT DISCLOSED",
                            "EnquiryPurpose": "02",
                            "EnquiryAmountFieldLength": "06",
                            "EnquiryAmount": "500000"
                          },
                          {
                            "Length": "04",
                            "SegmentTag": "I006",
                            "DateOfEnquiryFields": "13082022",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortNameFieldLength": "13",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortName": "NOT DISCLOSED",
                            "EnquiryPurpose": "00",
                            "EnquiryAmountFieldLength": "01",
                            "EnquiryAmount": "1"
                          },
                          {
                            "Length": "04",
                            "SegmentTag": "I007",
                            "DateOfEnquiryFields": "17062022",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortNameFieldLength": "13",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortName": "NOT DISCLOSED",
                            "EnquiryPurpose": "00",
                            "EnquiryAmountFieldLength": "01",
                            "EnquiryAmount": "1"
                          },
                          {
                            "Length": "04",
                            "SegmentTag": "I008",
                            "DateOfEnquiryFields": "31122021",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortNameFieldLength": "13",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortName": "NOT DISCLOSED",
                            "EnquiryPurpose": "06",
                            "EnquiryAmountFieldLength": "05",
                            "EnquiryAmount": "13990"
                          },
                          {
                            "Length": "04",
                            "SegmentTag": "I009",
                            "DateOfEnquiryFields": "13122020",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortNameFieldLength": "13",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortName": "NOT DISCLOSED",
                            "EnquiryPurpose": "10",
                            "EnquiryAmountFieldLength": "04",
                            "EnquiryAmount": "1000"
                          },
                          {
                            "Length": "04",
                            "SegmentTag": "I010",
                            "DateOfEnquiryFields": "10122020",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortNameFieldLength": "13",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortName": "NOT DISCLOSED",
                            "EnquiryPurpose": "05",
                            "EnquiryAmountFieldLength": "03",
                            "EnquiryAmount": "100"
                          },
                          {
                            "Length": "04",
                            "SegmentTag": "I011",
                            "DateOfEnquiryFields": "19042019",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortNameFieldLength": "13",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortName": "NOT DISCLOSED",
                            "EnquiryPurpose": "06",
                            "EnquiryAmountFieldLength": "05",
                            "EnquiryAmount": "40990"
                          }
                        ],
                        "End": [
                          {
                            "TotalLength": "0001735",
                            "SegmentTag": "ES07"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "ApplicationData": {
            "FormattedReport": true,
            "ConsumerConsentForUIDAIAuthentication": "N",
            "NTCProductType": "PL",
            "MFIBureauFlag": "True",
            "IDVerificationFlag": "False",
            "DSTuNtcFlag": "True",
            "CibilBureauFlag": "False",
            "Password": null,
            "MemberCode": "NB66529999_CIRC2CNPE",
            "GSTStateCode": "08",
            "ScoreType": "08",
            "Amount": "100",
            "Purpose": "05",
            "MFIDocRequest": "\n",
            "ReturnMessage": "\n",
            "DTTrail": {
              "Step": {
                "Name": "\n",
                "Duration": "\n"
              }
            },
            "Milestone": {
              "Step": "\n"
            },
            "Start": "\n",
            "InputValReasonCodes": "\n",
            "User": "NB6652DC01_PROD001",
            "BusinessUnitId": "23",
            "ApplicationId": "353867102",
            "SolutionSetId": "50",
            "EnvironmentTypeId": "2",
            "EnvironmentType": "Production"
          },
          "Decision": null,
          "ApplicationId": null
        }
      },
      "FileContent": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=="
    }
  ]
}
```

How to create Multiples columns and rows from json file and to be stored into data frame and use it for further analysis (loanId TransactionStatus AccountType OwenershipIndicator DateOpenedOrDisbursed DateOfLastPayment DateClosed DateReportedAndCertified HighCreditOrSanctionedAmountFieldLength HighCreditOrSanctionedAmount CurrentBalanceFieldLength CurrentBalance PaymentHistory1FieldLength PaymentHistory1 PaymentHistory2FieldLength PaymentHistory2 PaymentHistoryStartDate PaymentHistoryEndDate PaymentFrequency ActualPaymentAmountFieldLength ActualPaymentAmount RateOfInterest etc)

Comment: Wanted to create multiples columns and store values itself.

Comment: But My purpose not yet resolve because I wanted to created multiple iteration on behalf of "ACCOUNT" and "ENQUIRY" and "Customer Demographic" and stored it in deferent DF (loanId ApplicationId Enquiry EnquiringMemberShortName EnquiryPurpose EnquiryAmount DateOfEnquiryFields)

Comment: loanId ApplicationId Account ReportingMemberShortNameFieldLength ReportingMemberShortName AccountType OwenershipIndicator DateOpenedOrDisbursed DateReportedAndCertified HighCreditOrSanctionedAmountFieldLength HighCreditOrSanctionedAmount CurrentBalanceFieldLength CurrentBalance PaymentHistory1FieldLength PaymentHistory1 PaymentHistoryStartDate PaymentHistoryEndDate ValueOfCollateralFieldLength ValueOfCollateral TypeOfCollateralFieldLength TypeOfCollateral RateOfInterestFieldLength RateOfInterest RepaymentTenureFieldLength RepaymentTenure EmiAmountFieldLength EmiAmount PaymentFrequency

Comment: So can you please help to me get Dataframe of above shared json data with multiple Iteration in account level and Enquiry level and Demographics level .

Answer (score 0):

more explaination

**load data**

```
import pandas as pd
import json

with open('FILE.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

df = pd.json_normalize(data, 'loans')
```

**print**ing all of the **columns** and **value** from **DataFrame**

```
cols = df.columns

print(len(cols))
# >> 98


for col in cols:
    print(col,':\n',df[col].values,end='\n\n')

# >> very long output so I'll not show it here
```

now, look into previous output to grab specific data

**for example, loanId:**

```
print(df['loanId'].values)
# >> ['11111111111111111']
```

**TransactionStatus**:

```
print(df['TransactionStatus.ResponseCode'].values)
print(df['TransactionStatus.ResponseMessage'].values)
# >> ['0']
# >> ['Success']
```

**AccountType**: *(it kinda nested very deep)*

```
# Column that contains AccountType

ThisColumn = 'DCResponse.ContextData.Applicants.Applicant.DsCibilBureau.Response.CibilBureauResponse.BureauResponseXml.SucessResponse.Account'

# List that contains AccountType
ThisList = df[ThisColumn].values

# Dict that contains AccountType
ThisDict = ThisList[0][0]

# Dict in a List inside key in Dict that contains AccountType
ThisSubDict = ThisDict['Account_NonSummary_Segment_Fields'][0]

# Key that contains AccountType
AccType = ThisSubDict['AccountType']

print(AccType)
# >> 02
```

## Full code

without explaination:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

with open('FILE.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

df = pd.json_normalize(data, 'loans')

# get loanId
print(df['loanId'].values)

# get TransactionStatus
print(df['TransactionStatus.ResponseCode'].values)
print(df['TransactionStatus.ResponseMessage'].values)

# get AccountType
print(df['DCResponse.ContextData.Applicants.Applicant.DsCibilBureau.Response.CibilBureauResponse.BureauResponseXml.SucessResponse.Account'].values[0][0]['Account_NonSummary_Segment_Fields'][0]['AccountType'])
```

for further analysis, yield data in the field that you need ,than I recommend build a new DataFrame for that.

Comment: How come created multiples variables and to be store data itself ?

Comment: Hi Krittipoom,Thanks for your reply. but wanted to create multiples columns of each objects like Account_NonSummary_Segment_Fields,AccountType,OwenershipIndicator,DateOpenedOrDisbursed,DateOfLastPayment,DateReportedAndCertified etc so that we will use it for furhter analysis

Comment: I want to be create columns like

Comment: How to create Multiples columns and rows from json file and to be stored into data frame and use it for further analysis (loanId TransactionStatus AccountType OwenershipIndicator DateOpenedOrDisbursed DateOfLastPayment DateClosed DateReportedAndCertified HighCreditOrSanctionedAmountFieldLength HighCreditOrSanctionedAmount CurrentBalanceFieldLength CurrentBalance PaymentHistory1FieldLength PaymentHistory1 PaymentHistory2FieldLength PaymentHistory2 PaymentHistoryStartDate PaymentHistoryEndDate PaymentFrequency ActualPaymentAmountFieldLength ActualPaymentAmount RateOfInterest  etc) pls help toget

Comment: Can anyone to help me to create above json file to data frame with  columns and rows of each objects